# Why does setting the minutes, hours and seconds to the same as a unix timestamp in Calendar give the wrong time?

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I have a timestamp: `1454716800` which is a representation of `02/06/2016 @ 12:00am (UTC)`. You can see it's 0 hours (on a 24 hour clock), 0 min, 0 seconds. But when I create it as a `Calendar` object and set the hours, minutes and seconds to be the same (00:00:00) it comes out at a different time! Why is this?

```
    long timestamp = 1454716800;

    Calendar theDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    //Set our date and adjust the time
    theDate.setTimeInMillis( timestamp * 1000 );
    theDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    theDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    theDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add what is expected and what is returned please.

Comment: What do you mean it *comes out at a different time*? What did you print and how?

Comment: Which TimeZone are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix Epoch Timestamps are apparently in UTC, but the default Java Calendar is not. To fix:

```
Calendar theDate = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC") );
```